# Compact supports of initial data implies compact supports for all $t$ in semi-linear wave equation $-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}u+\Delta u=u^3$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, compactness, wave-equation

Problem: Let $u(t,x,y)$ be a smooth real function defined on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^2$ where $t \in\mathbb R$ and $(x,y) \in\mathbb R^2$. We assume that it solves the following semi-linear wave equation:$$-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}u+\Delta u=u^3$$
If the supports of the initial data $u(0,x)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(0,x)$ are compact, prove that, for all $t_0\in \mathbb R$, the supports of $u(t_0, x)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} (t_0, x)$ are compact.$$$$
We know that for a general wave equation, the solution travels with finite speed. Since the initial data has compact support, from an intuition this problem is obvious. But I'm  a starter in PDE and I don't know how to explicitly and strictly write this intuition out into a formal solution. Are there any brief way to express this intuition out for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know a precise formulation of "finite propagation speed?" This seems like the crux of your question.

Comment: I may misunderstand, but what’s your formulation of "finite propagation speed?" Is it like “support or singularities of solutions only propagate at a bounded speed”？

Comment: Sure, something like that, but there should be a precise mathematical statement that says exactly what you mean. Once you know that, you'll probably find this question pretty easy.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger I’m new to PDE and I don’t know how to use a precise mathematical statement to describe "finite propagation speed“, which is why I’m asking. So what is the precise mathematical statement of finite propagation speed here?

Comment: There isn't one single precise statement that I'm aware of at least. There's several different things you might mean. One that's plausible is that you look at the backwards wave cone, and a smooth solution to the wave equation on that cone. If your solution vanishes on the wave cone, and so does its time derivative, then it vanishes on the interior also. That's not obviously related, but it's often the result that calls itself "finite propagation speed." (1/2)

Comment: Another thing that goes by this name is when you write down energy estimates for the solution to the equation. The connection is that these energy estimates are obtained by decomposing integrals over the interior as double integrals throughout the interior of the wave cone and transverse to the boundary. I'm no expert on PDEs myself, so without knowing what you know and what tools you have, I don't know how I can help short of just pointing you to e.g. Michael Taylor's book or Evans' book on the subject. Each has chapters dedicated to these ideas.